# Forcefully decrease performance of a goroutine

Tags: multithreading, performance, go, goroutine, throttling

My program is consuming hundreds of tasks(1) every minute. These tasks run in parallel and need to be consumed as soon as possible.

At times, a different kind of task(2) has to be computed. This one is way heavy and brings the CPU all the way to 100%, making all other tasks take longer.

This is an issue for me because I need all tasks of type (1) to be completed as fast as possible. I don't care if task (2) takes all the time in the world to finish.

Is there anything I can do to make the goroutine of task (2) take its time and have less priority cpuwise?

Comment: If there is no obvious point which task2 can yield while task1 is running, then run it in a separate process. You can call the subprocess directly, but there's a good reason systems often distribute background work with a message queue to multiple consumers, it gives you better control how and where the processing happens.

Comment: There exists a hack which you can use as a last resort: make task(2) always performed by the same goroutine (create such a goroutine once, and let it sleep when there's no task to perform), pin it to a particular OS thread using `runtime.LockOSThread`, and then use a platform-specific way to decrease that thread's CPU priority. Provided all the "normal" OS threads the Go runtime of your program creates have "normal" priority, your taks(2)'s goroutine will naturally be deprived of the CPU time when there's the shortage of it.

Comment: Still, a better approach is to break task(2) into subtasks and relinquish control _between_ performing them. This can either be direct–like calling `runtime.Goshed`–or indirect–by making these subtasks compete for the resources as task(1)s, say, being processed by the same work queues. The smaller the subtasks, the "less priority" the whole task will effectively has.

Comment: Yet another approach is to use explicit pacing (throttling). For instance, the venerable [`golang.org/x/time/rate`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/time/rate) is quite battle-tested. You can make your task(2)s draw tokens from such a rate limiter while _completed_ task(1)s add tokens to it. This way you can naturally balance relative priorities. Of course, this means the code of task(2) should be again split into subtasks, each of which must reach for the throttle before starting to execute.